# Hover effect on button created using anchor tag not proper

Tags: html, css

I have a button that is actually a link i.e. styled anchor tag and I cannot change it from anchor tag to input type 'button'. The problem that I am facing is that when text in this button is hovered it works perfectly, however, if hovering is done outside the text area and inside  the button, it does not work properly. Below are the button looks illustrating the same:

**Normal button in untouched state:**

[image: Normal button in untouched state]

**When hovered outside the text area but inside the box:**

[image: When hovered outside the text area but inside box]

**When hovered over the text area:**

[image: When hovered over the text area]

Below is the **JSP** code:

```
<jato:content name="ContentHref">
<div class="loginButton btn-red"><auth:href name="LoginURL" fireDisplayEvents='true'><span><jato:text name="txtGotoLoginAfterFail" /></span></auth:href></div>
</jato:content>
```

Below is the **styling** code:

```
.btn-red {
    border: 2px solid #c82127;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #c82127;
}
.btn-red:hover{
    border: 2px solid #c82127;
    background-color: #c82127;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me - if I convert the jsp to html - here is the link to the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/x4od1w7c/
Can you share the compiled html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following style.

```
.btn-red:hover * {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```